# How to get DBMS_ADDM report output through PHP

Tags: php, arrays, database, oracle, dbms-output

I am trying to get the ADDM report for Oracle Database. The output is in an array fashion as a .txt. I need to display it in a table row format. I'm not getting the desired output however.

```
  $today = date("His");
  $taskname =$username.$today;
  $taskquery = "BEGIN DBMS_ADDM.ANALYZE_INST(:tname,     :bsnap,:esnap,:instnum);END;";
  $stid = oci_parse($conn,$taskquery);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":tname", $taskname);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bsnap", $bsnap);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":esnap", $esnap);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":instnum", $inst);
  oci_execute($stid);
  $mainquery = "SELECT DBMS_ADDM.GET_REPORT(:tname) from dual";
  $stid = oci_parse($conn,$mainquery);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":tname", $taskname);
    oci_execute($stid);
    echo "<table border='1'>\n";
   while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
       echo "<tr>\n";
      foreach ($row as $item) {
           echo "    <td>" . $item . "</td>\n";
       }
  echo "</tr>\n";
  }
  echo "</table>\n";
```

Now this returns a error saying : Object of class OCI-Lob could not be converted to string

So I tried a var_dump  after doing a oci_fetch_all on $stid, and got this:

```
array (size=1)
  'DBMS_ADDM.GET_REPORT(:TNAME)' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '          ADDM Report for Task...and rest of the report shows here'
```

How can I echo that string that shows the report, because it displays it in the proper format I would get it on a shell. This is for a front end UI purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer on this question.
So it turns out that shell_exec function of PHP does a fantastic job of doing a simple cat command of the txt file in Linux format. So I simply output the variable that displays the string, into a txt file, and simply shell_exec('cat filename')

So simple!!!